# Add data to a list box from a dropdown

Tags: c#

I have a listbox (listBox) and a dropdown list(dropDown).  I want to be able to select an item from the dropDown and add them to the listBox.  I have looked everywhere for this but all I ever see is adding data from a datasource instead of a dropdown.  I want this to be dynamic so the listBox is populated based on the a user selected in the dropDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void SelectedIndex_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    myListBox.Items.Clear();
    myListBox.Items.Add(myDropDown.SelectedItem); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`listBox.Items.add(dropDown.selectedItem);`

?